# How to read switch matrix with 74HC595

Tags: arduino, shift-register

I would like to control the columns of a keypad with shift register.
The working prototype, using direct connection is here:
https://www.tinkercad.com/things/gRSmEPcnCXZ-3x3-switches-matrix
[image: arduino switch matrix]

I wanted to replace the column connections with a 74HC595 (the final design will use more switches)
I took this as example for the wiring:

[image: image from https://dronebotworkshop.com/shift-registers]
and ended up [this](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/89Cjn9FFESX-3x3-switches-matrix-with-shift-register):

[image]

[image]

Can somebody please tell me what did I wrong? I know that the original design doesn't require the extra power, so I assume, I need to direct that away from the matrix somehow.

edit:
this is the schematics generated by TinkerCad:
[image]

Edit: I connected the ic to the 5V pin, now, I get correct readings with low (10 Ohm) resistors, but also high current warnings too.
As I increase the resistor values, inconsistent results.

Comment: Please draw a proper schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka: added to the question

Comment: @vilmarci Unless you plan daisy-chaining more than one 74HC595 why not just use a decoder. I prefer the 7445. It's bullet-proof, can sink 80 mA and tolerate 30 V at its outputs. Four scan lines need only two wires to the Arduino. Eight? Just three. That can be reduced to two (clock and clear) if you use a 7476 as a counter. Big, massive output transistors on the 7445. Easier to drive with software whether direct or clocked counter. Can do 80 switches with just a few I/O. Just curious if there's an application reason you went with a more complex device. What's the ultimate goal?

Comment: Because all the basic tutorials about extending the Arduino are about the 74HC595 :) The plan is a chessboard, so I need to read 8x8 reed switches. I could use 2x8 pins, but wanted to spare some pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error/warning message is clear.

You have connnected a 5V data pin to a IC powered from 3.3V supply.

You can't do that, it is wrong and damages either the 5V chip providing the output or the 3.3V which gets 5V on it's input.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, that was mistake. I moved the connection to 5V and this error is gone. Otherwise, is the wiring good? I read always 0's regardless how I set the switches.

Comment: @vilmarci The hardware should work, but on the other hand, you are using quite strong pull-downs, and the diodes are unknown, as is your software.

Comment: If I put smaller resistors between the shift register and the matrix, like 10ohm, I get correct readings (so, at least the sw is working - it is in the TinkerCad project), but the chip breaks, because the current on Q3 is 34mA while the max is 25mA.

Answer (score 0):

In Arduino UNO the processor and all the I/O runs at 5V, connect the 74HC595 to the 5V pin of the Arduino instead of to the 3.3V pin.